# elasticsearch put a raw field inside a field

Tags: elasticsearch

Simply

this query

```
GET blabla/_search
{
  "_source": "city.raw"

}
```

gives zero results

but this one:

```
GET blabla/_search
    {
      "_source": "city"

    }
```

gives millions of documents.

the mapping for the field city is like this:

```
 "city": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
```

as you see the `.raw` is there. what am i dong wrong please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `city.raw` field is not stored in the `_source` it is just indexed so that you can search on it and perform aggregations on it.

What happens when you index a document such as

```
{ "city": "New York" }
```

is that

- the `city` field will contain the two tokens `new` and `york` (i.e. analyzed)
- whereas the `city.raw` field will contain the single token `New York` (i.e. not analyzed).

In your first example, you're trying to retrieve the `city.raw` field from the source, but no such field exists since it's a synthetic field created during the analysis process.